# How to get header values when click pivot table item in a gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This could be a little tricky so please bear with me.

I have this result from a gridview, the data came from a pivot table:

```
DateCreate        02/11/2013 02/19/2013  Total 
OrdersPendInvoice 0          1           1 
OrdersPendPickUp  1          15          16
```

Here the selectable items are the numbers, and just the numbers greater than zero.

So first I need for those items (the selectable ones) make them like linkButtons son when I click in one of them I can pass as reference (here the other tricky part) both headers.

Let's put an example:

If I clicked on number 15, which basically means that there are 15 OrdersPendPickUp for the date 02/19/2013. Then I will go to a different page with the references `02/19/2013` and `OrdersPendPickUp` and there show those 15 records. I have no problem with the last part as long as I have the references.

And for the `Total` case, I'd just need either the `OrdersPendInvoice` or `OrdersPendPickUp` (depending on the item selected) cause I will get all records for that reference no matter the date.

I did this but it's not much really, just changes the color of the items greater than zero :(

```
protected void gvOrdersProcessed_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.Pager)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (TryToParse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text) > 0)
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}

private int TryToParse(string value)
{
    int number;
    bool result = Int32.TryParse(value, out number);
    if (result)
        return number;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is tricky. However, give the following a try:

```
private List<string> _headers = new List<string>();

protected void gvOrdersProcessed_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //Collect the texts from the column headers
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
    { 
        for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            this._headers.Add(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
        }
    }

    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= e.Row.Cells.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            if (TryToParse(e.Row.Cells[i].Text) > 0)
            {
                string rowKey = e.Row.Cells[0].Text;
                string column = this._headers[i];

                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                link.Text = e.Row.Cells[i].Text;
                link.NavigateUrl="page.aspx?key=" + rowKey  + "&column=" +column;

                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Clear();
                e.Row.Cells[i].Controls.Add(link);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Links would be like:

**Normal values:** `~/page.aspx?key=OrdersPendPickUp&column=02/19/2013`
**Total:** `~/page.aspx?key=OrdersPendPickUp&column=Total`

Comment: Mt. Schneiders you rock! I just had to use another logic to get the headers since my headers here are 0,1,2... as many as columns I have. Thank you a lot for the time you spent helping me and developing a solution for me :)